# DocuSign - compositeTemplates - Fill template data & sign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to work with the compositeTemplate in order to send the document of a specific user after the sign process has been done.
This is the json Im sending:

```
    {
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "recipients": {
                "carbonCopies": [{
                    "email": "mtaranto@test1.com",
                    "name": "CC Name",
                    "recipientId": "3",
                    "emailNotification": {
                        "emailBody": "email text",
                        "emailSubject": "Completed!!!! this is custom",
                        "supportedLanguage": "en"
                    }
                }],
                "signers": [{
                    "email": "mauriciotaranto@test.com",
                    "name": "A Name",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Participant A",
                    "ClientUserId": "123456",
                    "Tabs": {
                        "TextTabs": [{
                            "TabLabel": "PreferredPhoneNumber",
                            "Value": "001234567"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "AlternatePhoneNumber",
                            "Value": "001234567"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "BirthMM",
                            "Value": "04"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "BirrthDD",
                            "Value": "18"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "BirrthYY",
                            "Value": "1981"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "DentalSchool",
                            "Value": "DentalSchool"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "MedicalSchool",
                            "Value": "MedicalSchool"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "OmsResidency",
                            "Value": "OmsResidency"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "Intership",
                            "Value": "Intership"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "Fellowship",
                            "Value": "Fellowship"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "TrainingArea",
                            "Value": "TrainingArea"
                        }],
                        "RadioGroupTabs": [{
                            "groupName": "RadioPhone",
                            "radios": [{
                                "selected": true,
                                "value": "Radio2"
                            }],

                        },
                        {
                            "groupName": "AlternatePhoneNumber",
                            "radios": [{
                                "selected": true,
                                "value": "Radio1"
                            }],

                        },
                        {
                            "groupName": "MemberShip",
                            "radios": [{
                                "selected": true,
                                "value": "Radio2"
                            }],

                        },
                        {
                            "groupName": "RiskManagement",
                            "radios": [{
                                "selected": true,
                                "value": "Radio2"
                            }],

                        }],
                        "checkboxTabs": [{
                            "TabLabel": "SuffixDDS",
                            "selected": true,

                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "SuffixMD",
                            "selected": true,

                        },
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            },
            "sequence": "2"
        }],
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "07a2484d-c144-4ad6-a218-85b96bcea4ca"
        }]
    }],
    "emailSubject": "Test flow with CC",
    "status": "sent"
}
```

As you can see Im also sending the client id property. This is because we are using the embedded solution.

But after create the envelope and get the recipient view this is what I see:

[image]

As you can see on the image the document does not have the tabs data on it and also it does not have the sing tabs (I create them on the template). The user has to drag and drop. And that is not what I'm looking for.

What Im missing?

Thanks!

Comment: is it possible for you to download and send your template to docusign.sso@gmail.com, I will run it in my account. I hope the data labels you are referring in CompositeTemplate is same what you configured in your servertemplates in DocuSign.

Comment: is `"roleName": "Participant A"` the roleName of the signer in your Template - `07a2484d-c144-4ad6-a218-85b96bcea4ca`, I think you have roleName is `Test` in the ServerTemplate. And same roleName you need to use in the CompositeTemplate so that DocuSign knows which recipient data you are sending the the JSON call.

Comment: Hi I will send you. Also, yes they are because if I use the same data on the TemplateRoles it works. So Im not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Amit! you nailed it. Was because of the role name! now is working! thanks a lot for help! much appreciated!

Comment: Please accept answer to both of your qs, so that others can benefit for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have roleName is `Test` in the ServerTemplate. And same roleName you need to use in the CompositeTemplate so that DocuSign knows which recipient data you are sending the the JSON call.